# Difference between IBM Tivoli Directory Server vs IBM Security Directory Server

Tags: db2, tivoli-identity-manager

Please help me understand if these are 2 different products or they are the same. Both are IBM products
If different, what are the feature differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same product, different name.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdse/6.3.1?topic=troubleshooting-directory-server-overview

> IBM® Security Directory Server, previously known as IBM Tivoli®
> Directory Server, is the IBM implementation of Lightweight Directory
> Access Protocol (LDAP). IBM Security Directory Server provides a
> specialized in which to store, organize, and retrieve information
> about objects.